# C# precise float variable

Tags: c#, variables

I have written one program,it  use float variables and after calculate some functions it doesn’t have sufficient precise result.
my program is

```
int x=0;
ts_sec = 1338526801;       
ts_usec = 113676;
while(ir<2)
{
    Console.Write("ts_sec:" + ts_sec+"\t");  
    Console.Write("ts_usec:" + ts_usec+"\t");
    if (x == 0)                          
    {  
        floatstart = ts_sec + ts_usec / 1000000; 
        Console.Write("startTime" + floatstart+"\t");
        x=x+1;  //x=1
    }             
    timeStamp = ts_sec + ts_usec / 1000000 - floatstart;                            // 
    Console.Write("timestamp is" + timeStamp+"\n");
    ts_sec = 1338526801;       
    ts_usec = 113676;
    ir++;
}
```

this is my out put:

> ts_sec:1338526801       ts_usec:113676  startTime1.338527E+09
>   timestamp is0 ts_sec:1338526801       ts_usec:113678
>   timestamp is0

but I want my output will be like this  and  I want my result  doesn’t have E .

> ts_sec:1338526801       ts_usec:113676    startTime:1338526801.11368
>   timeStamp:0 ts_sec:1338526801       ts_usec:113678
>   timeStamp:1.9073486328125e-006

Comment: If you know how a float is saved to memory you know that you can't be precise. Its saved like 1.23E12 or 1.23E-2 (you can style the E out but still lack of precision)

Answer (score 1):

First, change `float` (32-bit) to `double` (64-bit) to increase precision nearly two times; second if you don't want the result being in *scientific representation* (i.e. with "e") choose appropriate *formatting*:

```
  Double startTime = ...
  // Assuming that you want 5 digits after the decimal point
  String result = startTime.ToString("F5");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want more precision use `decimal`.

> The decimal keyword indicates a 128-bit data type. Compared to floating-point types, the decimal type has more precision and a smaller range, which makes it appropriate for financial and monetary calculations.